# Generating sourcemaps for app code using karma and webpack

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, aurelia

I have an ES6 (Aurelia) app that I'm running unit tests for using `karma` with `webpack` and `babel`.  I am able to generate source maps for the *test* files, but not for the *application* files.  My `karma.config` contains something like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: __dirname,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    exclude: [],

    files: [
      { pattern: 'spec-bundle.js', watched: false }
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'spec-bundle.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack: require('../webpack.config.babel'),

    webpackServer: { noInfo: true },

    ...
  });
}
```

My spec files are pulled into `spec-bundle` which looks something like this:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack');

var testContext = require.context('./unit', true, /\.spec\.(ts|js)$/);

function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

The source maps for my tests are loaded fine, but I can't get source maps for the application files to load.  Further, I can't get the source maps for the test files to **not** load, so I'm not even sure what is turning them on (removing the `sourcemaps` reference from the `preprocessors` does nothing).

How can I load these source maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `istanbul`, and this is how I fixed it:

Updated my `npm` tasks in `package.json` from:

```
"test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=node NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js",
"test:debug": "npm test -- --single-run=false --debug"
```

to:

```
"test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=node NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js",
"test:debug": "set mode=debug&&npm test -- --single-run=false --debug"
```

Then, in my `webpack.config.babel`, changed it from:

```
...(ENV === 'production' || ENV === 'development'
    ? [commonChunksOptimize({ appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap' })]
    /* ENV === 'test' */
    : [generateCoverage({ options: { 'force-sourcemap': true, esModules: true } })]
    ),
```

To:

```
...(ENV === 'production' || ENV === 'development'
    ? [commonChunksOptimize({ appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap' })]
    /* ENV === 'test' */
    : process.env.mode === "debug" ? [] /* coverage breaks inline source maps */
        : [generateCoverage({ options: { 'force-sourcemap': true, esModules: true } })]
    ),
```

Where `generateCoverage` is defined up top as `import generateCoverage from '@easy-webpack/config-test-coverage-istanbul'`

I didn't make any changes to `karma.config` or `spec-bundle`

**EDIT:**

I upgraded this project to Webpack version 2, which no longer supports `yargs` so I was not able to pass my `debug` arg to it.  To workaround I instead turned off `istanbul` at the `karma` level.  In my `karma.conf.js`

```
webpack: require('../webpack.config')({ coverage: !config.debug }),
```

and my updated script:

```
karma start test/karma.conf.js --single-run=false --debug=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change in file webpack.config.ts, this line:

```
    envDev(ENV !== 'test' ? {} : {devtool: 'inline-source-map'}) :
```

to

```
    envDev(ENV === 'test' ? {} : {devtool: 'inline-source-map'}) :
```

Comment: I am using ES6, not typescript.  And I have the following in my `webpack.config.babel.js`: `ENV === 'test' || ENV === 'development'
 ? envDev({ devtool: 'inline-source-map', debug: true })
 : envProd({})` which has no effect on which sourcemaps are loaded when I run tests